# Get the least sales in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Datarame

```
Fresh Milk Grocery Channel
20     50     80    Hotel
40     10     30    Restaurant
100    90     20    Cafe
120    150    80    Hotel
450    910    30    Restaurant  
10     90     20     Cafe
205    50     80    Hotel
403    10     30    Restaurant
10     90     20    Cafe
```

How to get the least sales made by a channel and print the name of the channel.

I think we need to do groupby. Tried it but it didn't work out. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: where is the sales column?

Comment: There is no Sales column. above dataframe only have sales of each item.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to combine all the items into one column:

```
df['sum_of_items'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Then you can use a simple groupby:

```
df.groupby('Channel')['sum_of_items'].sum()
```

The result is:

```
Channel
Cafe           450
Hotel          835
Restaurant    1913
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :minimum considering all columns**

**Min by Channel**

First we calculate the total for each Channel, we can use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) with [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
total_channel = df.melt('Channel').groupby('Channel').value.sum()
```

or

```
total_channel = df.sum(axis=1).groupby(df['Channel']).sum()
```

**Output**

```
print(total_channel)

Channel
Cafe           450
Hotel          835
Restaurant    1913
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Then we use [`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html)

```
total_channel.idxmin()
#'Cafe'
```

---

**Case 2 Min by columns**

```
df.groupby('Channel').sum().idxmin()
Fresh       Cafe
Milk       Hotel
Grocery     Cafe
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can create a column with sum of all three columns like this and then get the channel which made a least spends like this.

```
df['Sales'] = df['Fresh'] + df['Milk'] + df['grocery']


df.groupby('Channel')['Sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('Sales', ascending = True).reset_index(drop=True).loc[0]
```